# I moved my script from HTML to external js. But this part doesn't work unless I put it on top of js file, why?

Tags: javascript

I use this part to show and hide (to top btn) in HTML.

```
// <!-- show (to top) btn -->
    window.onscroll = function () {
        scroll();
    };
    function scroll() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
            document.getElementById("toTopBtn-container").style.top = "96vh";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("toTopBtn-container").style.top = "110vh";
        }
    }
```

It was at the bottom and works normally. After I move it to an external js file and put it as it was in the HTML file at the bottom of the script, it doesn't work. But if I put it on top of the external js file, it works normally.

Help me understand why it is behaving like that, please.

**Here is the rest of the js script**

```
var menu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu");
var menuImg = document.getElementById("menuImg");
var closeMenuImg = document.getElementById("closeMenuImg");

menu.style.display = "block";
menu.style.marginLeft = "1000px";
menu.style.opacity = "1";
menuImg.style.display = "block";
closeMenuImg.style.display = "none";

function clickMenu() {

    if (menuImg.style.display == "block") {

        // btn animation
        menuImg.style.transform = "rotateZ(180deg)";
        menuImg.style.transition = "0.3s";
        // menu animation
        menu.style.marginLeft = "0";
        menu.style.opacity = "1";
        menu.style.transition = "0.5s";

        setTimeout(() => {

            menuImg.style.display = "none";
            closeMenuImg.style.display = "block";
            menu.style.display = "block";

            // untoggle animation
            menuImg.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
            menuImg.style.width = "80px";
            menuImg.style.transition = "0.3s";

        }, 200);

    } else {

        // btn animation
        closeMenuImg.style.transform = "rotateZ(-180deg)";
        closeMenuImg.style.transition = "0.3s";
        // menu animation
        menu.style.marginLeft = "1000px";
        menu.style.transition = "0.4s";

        setTimeout(() => {

            menuImg.style.display = "block";
            closeMenuImg.style.display = "none";

            // untoggle animation
            closeMenuImg.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
            closeMenuImg.style.width = "80px";
            closeMenuImg.style.transition = "0.3s";

        }, 200);

    }
}


var mobileWorkBtn = document.getElementById(mobile - work - btn);
var mobileContactBtn = document.getElementById(mobile - contact - btn);

function clickMobileMenuItem() {

    // btn animation
    closeMenuImg.style.transform = "rotateZ(-180deg)";
    closeMenuImg.style.transition = "0.3s";
    // menu animation
    menu.style.marginLeft = "1000px";
    menu.style.transition = "0.4s";

    setTimeout(() => {

        menuImg.style.display = "block";
        closeMenuImg.style.display = "none";


        closeMenuImg.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
        closeMenuImg.style.width = "80px";
        closeMenuImg.style.transition = "0.3s";

    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Path you added to the script must be wrong when you moved to external js file. Check the filePath you added in script tag.

Comment: anything on the console about errors? .. the two lines with "mobileWorkBtn" .. that's not an ID-string there!

Comment: the path is fine and the code is working fine except for the first part of the question. please read the question carefully. if I put the first part under the second code in external js, the small part code only doesn't work, the rest of code works. but if I put it on top, it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mobileWorkBtn = document.getElementById(mobile - work - btn);
var mobileContactBtn = document.getElementById(mobile - contact - btn);
```

is probably meant to be:

```
var mobileWorkBtn = document.getElementById("mobile-work-btn");
var mobileContactBtn = document.getElementById("mobile-contact-btn");
```

Comment: you are focusing on the wrong point man.  I actually removed these two because I realized they are not used in the following function, so no need for them.

Comment: your own answer says you removed the lines .. in both cases we have removed a parsing error, which stops things below it being evaluated properly. another cause for this is often mismatched parentheses, curly braces or even unclosed strings.

Comment: yes, I think it was one of these. I don't know which one. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

never mind guys,

after I removed the two variables,

```
var mobileWorkBtn = document.getElementById(mobile - work - btn);
var mobileContactBtn = document.getElementById(mobile - contact - btn);
```

and restart the browser and editor, suddenly it works on the bottom as it was in HTML.

the annoying part is, I still don't know why it didn't work first time !?